# Как прикрепить файл excel к письму?

Tags: android, kotlin

Всем привет, столкнулась с проблемой. В приложении создаю файл excel (через библиотеку aspoae.cells), в который записываю данные. Также создаю `Intent` для открытия почтового клиента. Как прикрепить созданный файл к письму?

```
protected fun sendEmail(wb: File) {
    Log.i("Отправить письмо", "")
    val TO = arrayOf("")
    val CC = arrayOf("")
    val emailIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    emailIntent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
    emailIntent.type = "text/plain"
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO)
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC)
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "")
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "")
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Отправка письма..."))
        finish()
        Log.i("Завершение отправки...", "")
    } catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Toast.makeText(
            this@StartActivity,
            "Почтовый клиент не установлен!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: так же, как и любой другой, видимо...

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить:

```
   putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri)
```

Надо только обложиться пермишенами и получением `fileUri: Uri` через `FileProvider`